# UIDatePicker mode countDownTimer value changed callback not calling first time

Tags: ios, swift

I am having this strange issue in UIDatePicker mode .countdownTimer

[image]

When I add constraints of up/down/left/right to the datePicker view, the callback is not registered for the first time. However, if I add only Alignment constraints, the callback works everytime. Maybe its a bug. Any idea why isn't it working?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    }

    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
        print("Selected value \(sender.countDownDuration)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce this. Looks like a bug in the cocoa touch framework.

Answer (score 3):

OK, it's a long-known bug in iOS, since iOS 7 or so.
You can work-around in your case if you put the following somewhere into `viewDidLoad`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.datePicker.countDownDuration = self.datePicker.countDownDuration
}
```

Seems nasty, and is nasty.

Comment: I solved it by putting date picker with horizontal and vertical alignments inside a uiview with top bottom left right constraints

Comment: This does not work for me in iOS 15.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround of setting the countDownDuration didn't work for me. Instead the only way I managed to solve this is to replace the UIDatePicker with a UIPickerView and populate it myself with 4 components: hours, "hour(s)" label, mins, "min(s)" label.

- The hours are 0-23
- The hours label is a single row component, which
  gets reloaded when the hours are changed so that it switches to
  "hour" when it's 1 hour
- The mins are 0-59
- The mins label is the same
  as the hours label

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue in SwiftUI (using a "UIDatePicker" created with "UIViewRepresentable") by appending an "onAppear" to the picker and inside the closure updating the state variable used for tracking the duration to any value that is not the default value. This forces a programmatic update on the first render which then allows the picker to work correctly on the first spin.